# Why is my structure zeroed out even when I did not return a object?

Tags: c

Ive been dabbling in some c code and initialized a cat structure like so

```
typedef struct 
{
   int age;
   char *name;
   char *favoriteQuote;
} Cat;
```

I created two functions, one to initialize the cat object and one to zero out the memory that look like so

```
Cat initialize_cat_object(void)
{
   Cat my_cat;
   my_cat.age = 3;
   my_cat.favorite_quote = "A day without laughter is a day wasted";
   my_cat.name = "Chester";
   return my_cat;
} 

Cat destroy_cat_object(void)
{
  Cat my_cat;
  memset(&my_cat, 0, sizeof(my_cat));
  //--forgot to return 'my_cat' here--
}
```

my main function looks like so

```
void main(void)
{
    Cat my_cat;
    my_cat = initialize_cat_object();
    printf("Creating cat\n")
    printf("Name: %s\nFavoriteQuote: %s\nAge: %d\n", my_cat.name,
            my_cat.favorite_quote, my_cat.age);

   my_cat = destroy_cat_obect();

   printf("CAT DESTRUCTION\n");
   printf("Name: %s\nFavoriteQuote: %s\nAge: %d\n", my_cat.name,
           my_cat.favorite_quote, my_cat.age);

}
```

The output of the program was the expected output of
[image: Program output]

It wasn't until I went back to the source code that I noticed I had forgotten to return the Cat object who's memory was zeroed out, However the program still shows the expected output, but if I try to omit the return statement of the 'initialize_cat_object' function, the output of the data is corrupt

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that 'destroy_cat_object' returns the zeroed out memory, but how could this be?

Comment: Wouldn't it return the values of 'my_cat' and set them to the object?

Comment: Where is the `my_cat` declared that you're using in `main`?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior because you aren't returning anything.

Comment: Why would it? You didn't tell it to. That's undefined behavior, and I think your compiler would give you a warning.

Comment: @Harrythehacker Yes, it will and I've got confused. Sorry. Yet you better take a pointer to the object you want to initialize/destroy, and work with it.

Comment: @Harrythehacker Yes, it would. Structures are viable value-results in C. So long as you're not returning addresses of expiring objects (and you're not) what you have (had you remembers to `return my_cat;`) would be fine. That said, you have *undefined behavior*. You basically made a liar of your function by claiming to return something, then not following through with it. I question the logic in the actual code, even with the UB fixed.

Comment: Your method `destroy_cat_object` does not destroy the object. It just zero's out the fields of a local variable. It has no effect on the variables of the same name in the other functions. It's not clear where you're storing the copy of the object returned from `initialize_cat_object`. You don't declare a variable in main(), so it's not on the stack. Perhaps you've defined it as a global somewhere?

Comment: As indicated by @ChrisTurner , assuming `my_cat` is a global variable (not deleted in `main`, you should consider that global variables are automatically initialized to zero.

Comment: @Eugene Sh Thats ok, We all have our off moments, like Chris just noted I forgot to declare the cat object

Comment: @WhozCraig So basically it is still returning the zeroed out memory even though I didn't tell it to?

Comment: @Harrythehacker Trying to make sense of non-existent definition is folly at best. Had your compiler been reasonably equipped with heightened warning levels and treated them as errors, you would have found the mistake and corrected it earlier. Beyond that, there is little sense in seeking worthwhile conclusions from this.

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted some ones comment, sorry about that, If you could re-write it that would be great

Comment: @Harrythehacker you should cut'n'paste your actual code rather than re-typing it so you don't make mistakes like that

Comment: The program runs fine.  If you didn't expect change in behavior when changing the program, then all I can say is 'Oh Boy!'+(face palm)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`destroy_cat_object` doesn't have a `return` statement. [C11 6.9.1p12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12) says:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

---

It is however perfectly OK C-standard-wise to have a function with a return type but which *doesn't* have a `return` statement before the closing bracket. Calling such a function is also perfectly OK.

What is not OK however is using the return value of the function call if the function didn't terminate with a `return` statement that explicitly returns a value.

You might want to enable some extra diagnostics in your compiler settings if you do not get a message for this.

Answer (score 2):

Registers aside. There are three places where your data may be stored in C:

1. Constant data which is read only and is stored inside your binary;
2. Data on the stack;
3. Data stored in dynamic memory retrieved by the means of memory allocation functions.

In your case we are talking about stack. Stack is a LIFO queue elements of which are valid and accessible so long as they are not popped out of it. So if you have a function like this:

```c
typedef struct {
  int a_val;
  float b_val;
  char c_val;
} a_t;

a_t* func(void) {
  a_t a = {1, 1., 'a'};
  return &a;
}
```

"a" would be residing in stack until func returns, hence after func returns it's pointer becomes invalid and points someplace in stackspace. On the most systems stack won't be zeroed therefore until some other data overwrites it it may be possible to get some data by that pointer, which may be misleading.

So what should you do? Something like this:

```c
void initialize_cat(Cat*);
void clear_cat(Cat*);

int main() {
  Cat my_cat;
  initialize_cat(&my_cat);
  // do kitty stuff
  clear_cat(&my_cat); // cat's private data must not be compromised
}
```

---

When function returns a structure this is actually achieved with a cooperation from a caller (I'm talking SysV x64 ABI here and may be wrong for other cases). Basically caller allocates space on stack enough to store the returned structure and passes pointer to it as an implicit first parameter. callee is using this pointer to write data later on.

So the two cases:

```c
Cat callee(void) {
   Cat my_cat = { .age = 5 };
   return cat;
}

void caller(void) {
   Cat my_cat = callee();
}
```

And:

```c
void callee(Cat *my_cat) {
   my_cat->age = 5;
   return cat;
}

void caller(void) {
   Cat my_cat;
   callee(&my_cat);
}
```

Are pretty much the same.